# Many-To-Many binding issue with <form:select> in Spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, many-to-many

When I load page for create a new article, all categories is displayed in select box.

When I complete form for a new article and click on the submit button, it saves all data from form to the database but categories isn't joined with an article.

Do you understand me what I think? What could be an issue?

**ArticleController.class**

```
@Controller
public class ArticleController {

@Autowired
ArticleService articleService;

@Autowired
CategoryService categoryService;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@ModelAttribute("article")
public Article construct() {
    return new Article();
}

/**
 * Method displays page with all articles, categories and users
 * (articles.jsp)
 * */
@RequestMapping("/admin/articles")
public String articles(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
    return "articles";
}

/**
 * Method for display article's detail (article-detail.jsp)
 * */
@RequestMapping("/admin/articles/{id}")
public String userDetail(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id) {
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("article", articleService.findById(id));
    return "article-detail";
}

/**
 * Method for display article's add page (article-add.jsp)
 * */
@RequestMapping("/admin/articles/new")
public String articleAdd(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
    return "article-add";
}

/**
 * Method for save article
 * */
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/articles/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,
        BindingResult result) {
    Date publishDate = new Date();
    article.setPublishDate(publishDate);
    articleService.save(article);
    return "redirect:/admin/articles.html?success=true";
}

/**
 * Binder for required date format
 * */
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "publishDate",
            new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
}}
```

**article-add.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ include file="../layouts/taglibs.jsp"%>

<form:form commandName="article" cssClass="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <form:hidden path="id" class="form-control input-sm" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulek</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:input path="title" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="content" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:textarea path="content" cssClass="form-control" rows="10" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="categories" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kategorie</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:select path="categories" items="${categories}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"      multiple="true" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Uživatel</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form:select path="user.id" items="${users}" value="${user.id}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"  cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Uložit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Category.class**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Size(min=3, max=20, message="Název musí obsahovat 3-20 znaků!")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Article> articles;

/**
 * Getters and setters
 * */
}
```

Comment: `"don't save data in the database"`: because there's no code to save data in a db here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-- SOLVED --**

I solved this problem by adding:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws     Exception {
binder.registerCustomEditor(Category.class, "categories", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
@Override
public void setAsText(String text) {
    Category c = categoryService.findById(Integer.parseInt(text));
    setValue(c);
}
});
```

}